# mongoose FindbyId and where array match to a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query a user by id, and then bring only the the foods that match to a type, how can i do this?

```
var type = 'fish';

var id = '597a348286ffe50d882a3033';

User.findById(id, { 'food.type': type }, 'food', function(err, model) {

    if (err) {

        console.log(err);

    }
    if (!model) {

        console.log('no model');
    }

    if (model) {

        console.log(model);

    }

});
```

Comment: What's the structure of your document?

Comment: `var User = mongoose.Schema({
 
 name: String,
 telephone: String,
 email: String,

 food: [{
 
    type: String,
    name: String,
 price: String
 
 }]

}`

Answer (score 2):

I would use `aggregate` combined with `$filter`:

```
  User.aggregate([{
      $match: { '_id': ObjectId('597a348286ffe50d882a3033') }
  }, {
      $project:
      {
          food: {
              $filter: {
                  input: '$food',
                  as: 'food',
                  cond: {
                      $eq: ['$$food.type', type]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }])
```

This will first select the document matching the given Id then will return the list of foods of the given type.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the food after you get the user.

```
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
        console.log('no user');
    }
    if (user) {
        var food = user.food.filter(function (food) { return food.type === type; });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an obj something like this

```
var obj =
{
_id:'597a348286ffe50d882a3033',
'food.type' : 'fish'
}
```

and then pass this function as filter

```
User.find(obj, function(err, model) {

    if (err) {

        console.log(err);

    }
    // find will return empty array and not null
    if (!model.length) {

        console.log('no model');
    }

    if (model) {

        console.log(model);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding the object using mongo _id field you don't have to use additional filter function after query execution you directly specify in the search query

```
Model.findOne({_id: '123jasdoisd123', 'food.type': type }, 
  function(err, food){
    if(err) return err;
    if(!food){
      // send the empty data
     return []
    }
    return food;
  }
)
```